# Custom trackpad mapping doesn't work for all applications

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome, trackpad, scrolling

I found out I could invert my trackpad scrolling, so as to work more like the OS X "natural scrolling", which I liked better.

To do that, I run the following command on startup:

```
xinput set-button-map 11 1 2 3 5 4 7 6
```

Where 11 is the touchpad id (found with `xinput list` and `xinput test 11`). This inverts the vertical and horizontal two-finger scrolling, and works fine in Terminal, Chrome, Document Viewer, etc.

However, it doesn't work in Nautilus and some applications such as the Update Manager, as they keep the usual mapping. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 x64

**Why does this mapping work for some applications but not for others?** I know there is software I can download to do the same, but this method seemed "cleaner".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve the problem: [Read this](http://andym3.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/fixing-natural-scrolling-in-ubuntu-12-04/) if you're having the same issue.

At least it worked for me, since my trackpad is a Synaptics. This changes the direction from the driver level, which is before the X mapping. Be sure to reset the button map to the original, or you'll get "normal scrolling" in most applications, since it would be being inverted twice.